# Nexmo: Identifying missed call via Nexmo callback

Tags: vonage

I had forwarded call to another number using nexmo LVN. Now if somebody call to my LVN, call will be forwarded to my provided forward number. It happens properly and status webhook is called when call is completed with some parameters. Upon analyzing I found that parameters in webhook does not provide any information if call is picked or was it a missed call?

How can I find an inbound call is a missed call?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the documentation](https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/guides/call-flow#event-objects) I believe that your status webhook should receive either a `timeout` or `unanswered` event

Comment: Thanks Michael, but when we do "Forward to Phone" then in status we get ok or failed. I was not able to get any documentation on that.